# if y elseif en Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

Estoy sacando datos de una BD y según el numero que me regrese tiene que mostrar una class o otra. Estoy haciendo algo así pero no funciona.

```
@if ($vivienda->etiqueta == 1)
  <p class="pLab">¡ {{ $vivienda->etiqueta }} !</p>
@elseif ($vivienda->etiqueta == 2)
  <p class="pLab2">¡ {{ $vivienda->etiqueta }} !</p>
@endif
```

Si pongo en lugar de `elseif` pongo un `else` si que funciona, pero claro tengo que hacer hasta 7 estados distintos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no es mas facil hacer esto:

```
@switch(true)
    @case($vivienda->etiqueta == 1)
         <p class="pLab">¡ {{ $vivienda->etiqueta }} !</p>
        @break

    @case($vivienda->etiqueta == 2)
        <p class="pLab2">¡ {{ $vivienda->etiqueta }} !</p>
        @break
@endswitch
```

o quizas de esta forma:

```
 <p class="pLab{{$vivienda->etiqueta}}">¡ {{ $vivienda->etiqueta }} !</p>
```

Comment: ¿Por que no harias `@switch($vivienda->etiqueta)` ?

Comment: por razones de comparacion de mas de 1 caso por ejemplo `(viviendo > 2 && vivienda < 5)`

Comment: Me funciono lo que me decias, será más fácil pero soy totalmente nuevo en laravel, la parte de que me dices (quizas esto), eso no lo entiendo??

Comment: Hay alguna forma de acortar el código, tengo que hacer 7 comparaciones?

Comment: viendo tus classes se llama pLab1 y pLab2 lo que haria esto es agrega class="pLab{{$vivienda->etiqueta}} que a la hora de imprimir no es mas que class="plab2" o class="plab1" depediendo del valor de $vivienda->etiqueta

Comment: entonces @Bryro no sera necesario hacer tantas comparaciones?

Comment: exacto solo que tus clases tenga un numero luego de plab1 u plab2 o plab3 y asi =D

Comment: Grande!!! jamás se me ocurrio hacer eso jajajjaja gracias voy hacerlo así